# How to know the activity of each Kinesis shard?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis

I use AWS Kinesis stream with several shards. The partition keys I set when I put records in the stream is not constant, to map the records to every shards.

To be sure about the fact that every shard is used, how can I monitor the activity of the shards ?

I saw that in a enhanced level of AWS Cloudwatch, the metrics of Kinesis can be split by shards. That is not my case, and as my need is just occasional, I don't want to pay for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can enable shard level metrics when you want, then disable when you don't need to. Although you specified that you did not want this solution, this is by far the best way.
2. On the consumer side, you can use custom logging. For each record batch processed in your IRecordProcessor implementation, you can count the incoming data counts for each shard. [Sample code here](https://github.com/az3/kinesis-three/blob/4b79a70d2ec175fea8a22b0c99acb965babcaef0/src/main/java/com/cagricelebi/aws/kinesis/three/SampleRecordProcessor.java#L52). You can even add 3rd party metrics platforms (such as Prometheus).
3. You can customize producer, and log `PutRecordResponse`s. It returns "your data is placed under XXX shard" for each Put call. [See AWS Documentation for details](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html#API_PutRecord_ResponseElements).

Generally, if your have a problem regardnig non-uniform data distribution between your shards, best way is to use random partition key while sending data in Kinesis Producer applications.